# How to print a SQL Server Reporting services (2008) report on command prompt?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

Is there a way to automatically print a SQL Server Reporting services (2008) report on command prompt?
For eg: We can save a pdf file using rs.exe utility. I want to print a pdf using rs.exe utility.
Can we do that?